# Get HTML Element Data with PostBack on an ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

One site would take data from the site var. C# PostBack method.But when the page's source code as submitted does not renewed. Object Can not Be Coming Referanced error. So I do post but the page refresh itself. This post has been displayed next to new data coming from the user how can I get?

Comment: Can you please reword your question? I'm having a hard time understanding what your asking.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please clarify your question. Are you talking about a `NullReferenceException`? Maybe you should post a small amount of the code that causes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow your question, but your title makes it sound like you want to get the data from an HTML form element on a post back in C#. To do that, all you have to say is

```
Request["myElement"]
```

if you have an HTML element defined as

```
<input name="myElement" ...
```

Comment: Is it not compiling or failing at runtime? Depending on where you are, you might have to say HttpContext.Current.Request["myElement"]